# pick replanning

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how do i set the number of planning attempts for when i do a pick. i am using a single grasp.

group_->setNumPlanningAttempts(25); doesn't seem to do it for me.

my terminal currently shows me :

```
[ INFO] [1413790159.614425456]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1413790159.621392483]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1413790160.622764995]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm'
[ INFO] [1413790161.398305226]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group arm.
[ INFO] [1413790161.398794822]: Looking around: no
[ INFO] [1413790161.399136122]: Replanning: no
[ INFO] [1413790217.348584478]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1413790217.371861830]: Added plan for pipeline 'pick'. Queue is now of size 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195350/pick-replanning/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++ you have:

```
moveit_msgs::PlanningOptions options;
options.replan = true;
options.replan_attempts = y;

moveit_msgs::PickupGoal goal;
goal.planning_options = options;
```

Or in you case:

```
group_->allowReplanning(true);
```

In python you have:

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(blablabla)
group.allow_replanning(True)
```

There is no attribute in the Python API for the number of attempts but if you need to change it you can implement it yourself in move_group.py

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1